# Interstitial Ad doesn't appear

Tags: html, admob, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-admob

I can't do a simply html page with an Interstitial Add. I'm new in programming and I have no idea what's wrong in this code. I'm doing an app with phonegap. I added also `<gap:plugin name="com.admob.plugin" version="3.0.0" source="plugins.cordova.io" />` to my config.xml. Please help. That's what I already have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showInterstitial(){
    admob.isInterstitialReady(function(isReady){
        if(isReady){
            admob.showInterstitial();
        }else{
            alert("need cached before show");
        }
    });
}
function onInterstitialReceive (message) {
    alert("onMInterstitialReceive ,you can show it now");
}
function onReceiveFail (message) {
    var msg=admob.Error[message.data];
    if(msg==undefined){
       msg=message.data;
    }
   alert("load fail: "+message.type+"  "+msg);
}
function onDeviceReady() {
    admob.initAdmob("ca-app-pub-5461976332457981/1789654352","ca-app-pub-5461976332457981/7220849555");
    document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialReceive, onInterstitialReceive, false);
    document.addEventListener(admob.Event.onInterstitialFailedReceive,onReceiveFail, false);
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready',onDeviceReady, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new plugin specification (with hyphens instead of dots):

```
<gap:plugin name="phonegap-admob" source="npm"/>
```

Then your code should be like this (you can also see here an example on how autoshow interstitials every 2 minutes: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/setOptions):

```
var isAppForeground = true;
var isInterstitialAvailable = false;

function onAdLoaded(e) {
  if (isAppForeground && e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
    isInterstitialAvailable = true;
  }
}

function onAdOpened(e) {
  if (isAppForeground && e.adType === admob.AD_TYPE.INTERSTITIAL) {
    isInterstitialAvailable = false;
    admob.requestInterstitialAd(); // Request next interstitial
  }
}

function onPause() {
  if (isAppForeground) {
    admob.destroyBannerView();
    isAppForeground = false;
    isInterstitialAvailable = false;
  }
}

function onResume() {
  if (!isAppForeground) {
    setTimeout(admob.createBannerView, 1);
    setTimeout(admob.requestInterstitialAd, 1);
    isAppForeground = true;
  }
}

function registerAdEvents() {
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdLoaded, onAdLoaded);
  document.addEventListener(admob.events.onAdOpened, onAdOpened);

  document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
  document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}

function initAds() {
  var ids = {
    ios : {
      banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
      interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
    },
    android : {
      banner : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",
      interstitial : "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII"
    }
  };

  var admobid = (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? ids.android : ids.ios;

  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          admobid.banner,
    interstitialAdId:     admobid.interstitial,
    autoShowInterstitial: false,
    isTesting:            true // False on production apps
  });

  registerAdEvents();
}

function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  if (window.admob) {
    initAds();
    admob.createBannerView(); // display a banner at startup
    admob.requestInterstitialAd(); // cache an interstitial
  } else {
    alert('Admob plugin not ready');
  }
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function showInterstitial() {
  if (isInterstitialAvailable) {
    admob.showInterstitialAd();
  } else {
    console.log('Interstitial is not yet available');
  }
}
```